# How to use foreach in R to create a nested loop?

Tags: r, foreach, correlation

I'm failing to devise correct code to run a nested loop using foreach. I'm using a huge dataset so parallelisation is needed here.

I need to sample at random 1/4 of the dataset without replacement 4 times (so the full dataset is resampled), and compute the correlation coefficient and p value for each pair of variables 4 times. The code I have been working on is below, I am aiming for an output that looks something like this (with rbinding each of the outputs from each quarter sampled).

```
     #from one of the quarters
      estimate  pvalue  Var1 Var2
      0.678     0.03    a     b
      0.754     0.04    a     b
      0.546     0.01    a     b
      0.567     0.03    a     b
     -0.234     0.14    a     c
     -0.321     0.34    a     c
     -0.456     0.43    a     c
     -0.456     0.52    a     c
      

      x <- colnames(df)
      df_use <- data.frame(t(combn(x,2)), stringsAsFactors=F)
      a <- 1/4 

    registerDoParallel(cl <- makeCluster(6))

 res <-
  foreach(i=1:4, .combine='rbind') %:%
     foreach(j=1:nrow(df.2), .combine='rbind', .packages=c("magrittr",  "dplyr")) %dopar% {
 df.2 = dplyr::sample_frac(df_use, a, replace = FALSE)
   out.frac = broom::tidy(cor.test(prac4[,df.2[j,1]],
                                   prac4[,df.2[j,2]],
                       method = "spearman")) %>% 
         mutate(Var1=df.2[j,1], Var2=df.2[j,2])
 c(out.frac$estimate, out.frac$p.value, out.frac$Var1, out.frac$Var2)
}
```

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT: all the above is doing is dividing the main df_use into 4 and then the correlation coefficient and p values for each pair of variables are being repeated 4 times ( they are exactly the same and this is unlikely to be the case for every pair tested).

The aim is to randomly sample a 1/4 of any pair dataset values ( when considering correlation between two variables) and do this 4 times, so its unlikely to repeat the exact same correlation and p value for every two variables tested in this large dataset.

Answer (score 1):

I would tackle it in a simpler way than the above and because I am not 100% sure if you are using 1/4th each time you do this 4-times or you are doing this on each 1/4th for all 4 runs, it may take tweaking.

But my process would be

#this is in some places pseudo code, because yours is hard to parse out without more clarity.

But you need to figure out how to set of the analysis of your data. That could also be done with a function that takes a number of samples and calls the `plan()` and uses assign to create data samples and outputs equal to the sampling quantity. You can decide the details.

But in general I avoid loops at all costs. Using future allows you to start a thread and allow R to move onto another processing task before the last one has finished

```
require(future)
sampling_function<- function(df){data%>%
             sample=sample_frac( size = .25, replace = FALSE)
             return(sample)}
plan(multiprocess) #allows for parallelization

d1<-sampling_function(df)
out1<-analysis_code(d1) #will run and R will move on to next line in new thread

d2<-sampling_function(df)
out2<-analysis_code(d2) #will run and R will move on to next line in new thread

d3<-sampling_function(df)
out3<-analysis_code(d3) #will run and R will move on to next line in new thread

d4<-sampling_function(d4)
out4<-analysis_code(d1) #will run and R will move on to next line in new thread
```

Then you can bind your outputs together. As I said, I think with a stronger sense of what you are doing (relative to one subsample per pass or 4 permuted subsamples per pass) you could create a function that sets up the parallelization too.

You can even include the rbind or dataframe aggregation of outputs into the function you write because if some previously requested task has not completed, R will wait for it to do so using `future` methods.